# BANNER adview causes CPU usage when app is in the background (Paused/Stopped)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, admob

Can you please have a look at the below problem

Setup:
admob SDK v6.4.1
Android 
SMART_BANNER ( Inside a FrameLayout on top, Or inside Linear Layout as first view)

Description:
When an application is paused and stopped the activity must pause all its content and the CPU usage becomes nearly 0%. When Using the SMART_BANNER format the application continues to consume around 5%.

Answer (score -1):

Call `adview.destroy()` in `OnDestroy()`.

See [my blog post](http://pzoleeblogen.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/android-how-to-solve-adview-cpu-consuming/) about it.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, especially "provide context for links" part.